# Save canvas surfaceview image in internal memoy

Tags: android, image, android-canvas, surfaceview

Hi guys I am using surface view in android in which I'm loading one image and top of the image I'm writing some text on it. Can anyone tell me how can I save that as an image in my internal storage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't read back from a SurfaceView. You can draw on a Bitmap using Canvas, and then blit the Bitmap to SurfaceView, and just save the Bitmap when desired.